Determine if columns of matrix are basis of quotient space
Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension $m$ with a fixed basis, $U \subseteq V$ be a subspace with basis given by the $l\times n$-matrix $A$ (i.p., $A$ has l.i. columns), and let $B$ be a $m\times n$-matrix for some $n$. I want to know if the images of the columns of $B$ in $V/U$ are linearly independent. Sure, this is the case iff. $(A\ B)$ has l.i. columns, which is the case if
$$\begin{aligned}
&\hspace{-2em}\det\bigl((A\ B)^T (A\ B)\bigr)\\
&= \det\begin{pmatrix}A^T A &A^T B \\ B^T A & B^T A \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \det A^TA \det\bigl(B^TB - B^TA (A^TA)^{-1} A^T B\bigr)\\
&= \det A^TA \det\bigl(B^T (I - AA^+)B\bigr),\\
\end{aligned}$$
which is zero if and only if $\det\bigl(B^T (I - AA^+)B\bigr)$ is.
And now I am stuck: what does this tell me? For example, why is $(I-AA^+)$ non-zero (probably because $\mathrm{rk} A < n$, but how do I see this?).

It's not entirely clear what you mean when you say that you're stuck; what exactly is it that you're trying to do that you are not able to do with your test?

Whatever it is that you are missing here, the following explanation might be helpful: $I - AA^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto $U^\perp$ (the orthogonal complement of $U$). $\det[B^T(I - AA^+)B]$ is zero if and only if $(I - AA^+)B$ has full column rank (i.e. linearly independent columns). More generally, if $M$ is any matrix whose nullspace is $U$, then the images of the columns of $B$ are linearly independent in $V/U$ if and only if the columns of $MB$ are linearly independent.

With that said, you might find the following alternative criterion to be appealing: compute a (full) QR decomposition of $A$. Take the (square) matrix $Q$ for which $A = QR$ and partition it into $Q = [Q_1 \ \ Q_2]$, where $Q_1$ has the same shape as $A$. The images of the columns of $B$ (under the canonical projection) are linearly independent in $V/U$ if and only if $Q_2^T B$ has linearly independent columns.

@BenGrossmann With “I'm stuck” I meant that I'd hoped for a simpler/handier/… expression. That $I-AA^+$ is the projection onto $U^\perp$ is enlightening. One thing is unclear to me: $U^\perp \cong V/U$, so why does $(I-AA^+)B$ have full column rank iff $\det B^T(I-AA^+)B = 0$ (and not $\neq 0$)?

Sorry, that's a mistake in that comment; I meant to say that it's non-zero if and only if $(I - AA^+)B$ has full column-rank.

Also, I'm trying to get an idea of what you have in mind as to what would count as "simpler/handier/...". All your descriptions of what you want are subjective, so the only way for an answerer to give you what you're looking for is to just take a guess as to the kind of condition that you find appealing. Since I'd rather not guess, I'm trying to get you to narrow down what you're looking for

It would help, I think, if you could explain what you find unappealing about the solution that you already found. I think that the determinant condition is pretty simple and handy, what is it about the solution that makes you disagree?
